# How to run a query and return the count

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

The method below currently queries the database with specific parameters and a limit, and when that query is complete, it queries again the database with those specific parameters, only replacing the select portion with a COUNT(*) to return the total possible results for the query.

For example:

```
SELECT c1, c2 FROM table WHERE c1 = 'something'
SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE c1 = 'something'
```

What I'd like to do is to run both of these queries at the same time and then bring the results together into an object, like below:

```
class SomethingResult {
  public List<T> data;
  public Long count;
}
```

How this might be solved with RxJava?

Also, is RxJava a good fit for this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RxJava is quite good for such cases. In your DB class:

```
//We'll use Single. Unlike Observable it returns only one value and then completes.
public Single<SomethingResult> getSomethingResultFromDb(Object params) {
    //we will use zip() operator to combine query results
    return Single.zip(
            doFirstQuery(params),
            doSecondQuery(params),
            (firstQueryResult, secondQueryResult) -> {
                //combine results into new SomethingResult
                return Single.just(somethingResult);
            });
}

private Single<List> doFirstQuery(Object params) {
    return Single.fromCallable(() -> { //or Single.defer()
        //your first db query with params
        return firstQueryResult;
    });
}

private Single<Long> doSecondQuery(Object params) {
    return Single.fromCallable(() -> { //or Single.defer()
        //your second db query with params
        return secondQueryResult;
    });
}
```

And call it like this

```
 YourDbObject.getSomethingResultFromDb(params)
     //apply schedulers with subscribeOn() and observeOn() operators
     .subscribe(somethingResult -> {
         //handle result
     }, error -> {
         //handle error
     });
```

Comment: That works! Thanks!!!